# Value not stored in Dynamic Array

Tags: excel, vba

Earlier it works fine but now the data is not store in array and the same is store in rng1
I can check in dubug windows by ***?rng1(1,1) or ?rng1(39,4)*** but vArray is giving error subscript out range.

```
Dim vArray() As Variant
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim ShNm As String
Dim lROW AS LONG 

ShNm = Sheets("Main").Range("G3")

lRow = Worksheets(ShNm).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 

Set rng1 = Worksheets(ShNm).Range("A1:D" & lRow)

vArray = Worksheets(ShNm).Range("A1:D" & lRow)
or        
vArray = Worksheets(Sheets("Main").Range("G3")).Range("A1:D39")
or
vArray = Worksheets("ListofSheets").Range("A1:D39")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
vArray = Worksheets("ListofSheets").Range("A1:D39").Value2
```

Comment: It works!...Thanks!  but what is value2 syntax where I can get help or more explanation on this.

Comment: If you have questions in Excel VBA about something just highlight the word you are looking help on (in this case, highlight `Value2`) and then press `F1`.

Comment: `.Value` will probably also work. `.Value2` is just faster than `.Value`. Therefore I prefer it and [if you are not dealing with dates or currencies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193553%28v=office.15%29.aspx) then there is no difference.